# How can i add a new user to MLab using a post request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I m really new in all these. I ve had some practice to create a database in Mongo DB and i can list the users. But i cant add a new user like ;

```
var newUser = {
      "first_name": req.body.first_name,
      "last_name": req.body.last_name,
      "email": req.body.email
    };
```

How can i add a new user to this Database? 
How can i handle it using a POST method?

Many thanks!!

```
var express = require ('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    var 
    baseMlabURL"https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mydatabase/collections/";
    var mLabAPIKey = "apiKey="; //my api key//
    var requestJson = require('request-json');

app.listen(port);
console.log("API is listening on" + port);

  app.get ('/myapi/v1/users/:id',
  function (req,res){
    console.log("GET/myapi/v1/users/:id");

    var id = req.params.id;
    var query = 'q={"id" : '+ id +'}';

    httpClient = requestJson.createClient(baseMlabURL);

    httpClient.get("user?" + query + "&" + mLabAPIKey,
    function(err, resMLab, body) {
   if (err) {
     response = {
       "msg" : "Error getting user."
     }
     res.status(500);
   } else {
     if (body.length > 0) {
       response = body[0];
     } else {
       response = {
         "msg" : "User not found."
       };
       res.status(404);
      }
   }
   res.send(response);
   }
  )
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After giving a try, i could get a simple post method and it works. But i have all users with an ID in the database and i would like to add an ID to the new user. 
I was checking Mlab Api parameters, should i use s`<sort order>`, l`<limit>` and try to order them first?

```
app.post ('/myapi/v1/newuser',
  function(req,res){

    console.log("POST/myapi/v1/newuser");

    var newRegister = {
      "first_name": req.body.first_name,
      "last_name": req.body.last_name,
      "email": req.body.email,
      "password" : req.body.password
    };

    httpClient = requestJson.createClient(baseMlabURL);


    httpClient.post("user?" + mLabAPIKey ,newRegister,

       function(err, resMLab, body) {
         res.send(
            {
              "msg" : "User added successfully "
            }
         );
       }
    );
  }
);
```